# VB code is not effecting the report, how it would be solved?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ProfitLoss_Refresh()
Dim PLRow As Long
Dim LastTransRow As Long
Dim LastResultsRow As Long
Dim AcctRow As Long
With Sheet1
    .Range("B7:I99999").ClearContents 'Clear Existing Report
    LastTransRow = Sheet2.Range("B99999").End(xlUp).Row 'Last transaction row

    Sheet2.Range("P3:Q3").ClearContents 'clear prev criteria
    Sheet2.Range("w3:aa99999").ClearContents 'clear prev results
    If .Range("e3").Value <> Empty Then Sheet2.Range("p3").Value = ">=" & .Range("E3").Value Else: Sheet2.Range("p3").Value = ">=01/01/2000" 'from date
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the sub?

Comment: ...and an explanation of what you're expecting this code to do would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you it's the part of the code that you published is the part that doesn't perform I took a good look at the way the worksheets are managed. In fact, I re-wrote your code to make it better legible (but without introducing changes).

```
Sub ProfitLoss_Refresh()

    Dim PLRow           As Long
    Dim LastTransRow    As Long
    Dim LastResultsRow  As Long
    Dim AcctRow         As Long
    
    With Sheet2
        LastTransRow = .Range("B99999").End(xlUp).Row       ' Last transaction row
        .Range("P3:Q3").ClearContents                       ' clear prev criteria
        .Range("w3:aa99999").ClearContents                  ' clear prev results
    End With
    
    With Sheet1
        .Range("B7:I99999").ClearContents                   ' Clear Existing Report
        If .Range("e3").Value <> Empty Then
            Sheet2.Range("p3").Value = ">=" & .Range("E3").Value
        Else
            Sheet2.Range("p3").Value = ">=01/01/2000"       ' from date
        End If
End Sub
```

You use CodeNames to address worksheets. If they wouldn't exist you would probably complain about then error message, and since you don't do that I must presume that they do. Therefore there is nothing wrong with your code that I can spot.

Therefore it may be your expectation. It seems that you are setting up an Advanced Filter. You don't show us where the filter is applied but the filter criteria point to a potential problem. If Range("E3").Value is a date it's unlikely to be of equivalent format to "01/01/2000". Check whether E3 is a proper date (a number) or indeed a string like "01/01/2000". Also check whether the dat you are filtering have true dates (numbers) or fake dates (strings). Read up on how Excel handles dates and how to filter for dates.

Comment: Sub ProfitLoss_Refresh()
Dim PLRow As Long
Dim LastTransRow As Long
Dim LastResultsRow As Long
Dim AcctRow As Long
With Sheet1

Comment: I checked the date format, but didn't find anything:
if you like to check the file and guide me, i can give you through wikicopy.com?

Comment: even there are some code or Data issue, there must be debug error, but running full, but after that data disappears from AdvancedFilterResult, if it is clear from there, then nothing will effects the other area of the report.

Comment: I never used wikicopy.com. But if you post your file there or elsewhere I shall try to get ahold of it and will take a look.

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/962510/P&L-1.xlsm

This is the file link, wikisend used to share working files online, it is 100% secure and safe!
plz if you give a look, hopefully fine dthe solution :(